# Reading vcf file data using python and re library

Tags: python, vcf-vcard

Here is content inside .vcf file data.

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:4.0
N:Muller;CCCIsabella;;;
FN:Muller
ORG:Bubba Gump Shrimp Co.
TITLE:Shrimp Man
PHOTO;MEDIATYPE=image/gif:http://www.example.com/dir_photos/my_photo.gif
TEL;TYPE=work,voice;VALUE=uri:tel:+16829185770
REV:20080424T195243Z
END:VCARD

BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:4.0
N:Mraz;CCCEdwardo;;;
FN:Mraz
ORG:Bubba Gump Shrimp Co.
TITLE:Shrimp Man
PHOTO;MEDIATYPE=image/gif:http://www.example.com/dir_photos/my_photo.gif
TEL;TYPE=work,voice;VALUE=uri:tel:+18083155095
REV:20080424T195243Z
END:VCARD

BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:4.0
N:Reynolds;CCCBrant;;;
FN:Reynolds
ORG:Bubba Gump Shrimp Co.
TITLE:Shrimp Man
PHOTO;MEDIATYPE=image/gif:http://www.example.com/dir_photos/my_photo.gif
TEL;TYPE=work,voice;VALUE=uri:tel:+15089473508
REV:20080424T195243Z
END:VCARD
```

I want my data in as below.

```
data = [{'name': 'Muller','phone': '+16829185770'}, {'name': 'Mraz', 'phone': '+18083155095'}, {'name': 'Reynolds','phone': '+15089473508'}]
```

but I am not getting data as above. Please help me out in this case. Here I am using re python package to solve.

```
import re
file = open('contacts.vcf', 'r')
contacts = []
for line in file:
    name = re.findall('FN:(.*)', line)
    tel = re.findall('tel:(.*)', line)
    nm = ''.join(name)
    tel = ''.join(tel)
    if len(nm) == 0 and len(tel) == 0:
        continue
    data = {'name' : nm, 'phone' : tel}
    contacts.append(data)
print(contacts)
```

getting below results name and phone are adding in defferent.

```
[{'name': 'Muller', 'phone': ''}, {'name': '', 'phone': '+16829185770'}, {'name': 'Mraz', 'phone': ''}, {'name': '', 'phone': '+18083155095'}, {'name': 'Reynolds', 'phone': ''}, {'name': '', 'phone': '+15089473508'}]
```

Comment: For anyone stumbling on this question I suggest following Reid Ballard’s advice and going for a dedicated module to parse VCF files like [PyVCF](https://pyvcf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/INTRO.html) or [allel’s read_vcf function](https://scikit-allel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/io.html#allel.read_vcf)

Comment: Or [vobject](https://pypi.org/project/vobject/), which worked best for my needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below code.

```
import re
file = open('vcards-2.vcf', 'r')
contacts = []
phone = []
for line in file:
    name = re.findall('FN:(.*)', line)
    nm = ''.join(name)
    if len(nm) == 0:
        continue

    data = {'name' : nm.strip()}
    for lin in file:
        tel = re.findall('pref:(.*)', lin)
        tel = ''.join(tel)

        if len(tel) == 0:
            continue

        tel = tel.strip()
        tel = ''.join(e for e in tel if e.isalnum())
        data['phone'] = tel
        break
    contacts.append(data)

print(contacts)
```

You will get below redults

```
[{'name': 'Muller','phone': '+16829185770'}, {'name': 'Mraz', 'phone': '+18083155095'}, {'name': 'Reynolds','phone': '+15089473508'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

### Try the below code

```py
import re
import json

from typing import List, Any


def get_contacts_from_vcf(filename: str) -> List[Any]:
    contacts = []
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        ln = ''.join(f.readlines())

    raw_data = ln.split("END:VCARD")

    for x in raw_data:
        s = re.search("FN:(.*)", x)
        fn = re.findall("TEL;(.*)", x)
        fn = [b_.strip() for b_ in fn]

        if s is not None and len(fn) >= 1:
            name = s.groups()[-1].strip()
            for num in fn:
                num_count = fn.count(num)
                if num_count > 1:
                    for n in range(1, num_count):
                        fn.remove(num)

            numbers = []
            for fn in fn:
                numbers.append(fn.split(':')[-1])
            tel = ', '.join(numbers)

            data = {
                "name": name,
                "Ph No(s)": tel
            }
            contacts.append(json.dumps(data) + ",")

    return contacts


print('\n'.join(get_contacts_from_vcf("bin.vcf")))
```

---

### Output:

```bash
{"name": "John", "Ph No(s)": "1234, 4321"},
{"name": "watt", "Ph No(s)": "121, 32444"},
{"name": "smith", "Ph No(s)": "55555"},
```

Answer (score 0):

Often time when debugging it is useful to use `print` at various points to figure out where the code is going awry. If you inserted `print(">",nm,tel)` after `tel = ''.join(tel)`, for example, you should get the following output:

```
>  
>  
>  
> Muller 
>  
>  
>  
>  +16829185770
>  
>  
>  
>  
>  
>  
> Mraz 
>  
[... continued...]
```

Obviously, this is because your `for` loop is operating on each *line* in the file instead of each card (technically, you even acknowledge this: `for line in file:`).

You may be interested in using a module for parsing this file (a quick google brought up the `vobject` package), which would eliminate the need for `re`. If you're feeling ambitious you may be able to parse it manually (not really familiar with the format, so here's an off-the-cuff example).

```
CARDMATCHER = re.compile(r"""
^                 ## Match at Start of Line (Multiline-flag)
    BEGIN:VCARD   ## Match the string "BEGIN:VCARD" exactly
$                 ## Match the End of Line (Multiline-flag)
.*?               ## Match characters (.) any number of times(*),
                  ## as few times as possible(?), including new-line(Dotall-flag)
^                 ## Match at Start of Line (Multiline-flag)
    END:VCARD     ## Match the string "END:VCARD" exactly
$                 ## Match the End of Line (Multiline-flag)
""", re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL|re.VERBOSE)

VALUERE = re.compile("""
^(?P<type>[A-Z]+) ## Match Capital Ascii Characters at Start of Line
(?P<sep>:|;)     ## Match a colon or a semicolon
(?P<value>.*)    ## Match all other characters remaining
""", re.VERBOSE)

class MyVCard():
    def __init__(self,cardstring):
        self.info = defaultdict(list)
        ## Iterate over the card like you were doing
        for line in cardstring.split("\n"):
            ## Split Key of line
            match = VALUERE.match(line)
            if match:
                vtype = match.group("type")
                ## Line Values are separated by semicolons
                values = match.group("value").split(";")

                ## Lines with colons appear to be unique values
                if match.group("sep") == ":":
                    ## If only a single value, we don't need the list
                    if len(values) == 1:
                        self.info[vtype] = values[0]
                    else:
                        self.info[vtype] = values

                ## Otherwise (Semicolon sep), the value may not be unique
                else:
                    ## Semicolon seps also appear to have multiple keys
                    ## So we'll use a dict
                    out = {}
                    for val in values:
                        ## Get key,value for each value
                        k,v = val.split("=",maxsplit=1)
                        out[k] = v
                    ## Make sure we havea list to append to
                    self.info[vtype].append(out)
    def get_a_number(self):
        """ Naive approach to getting the number """
        if "TEL" in self.info:
            number = self.info["TEL"][0]["VALUE"]
            numbers = re.findall("tel:(.+)",number)
            if numbers:
                return numbers[0]
        return None

def get_vcards(file):
    """ Use regex to parse VCards into dicts. """
    with open(file,'r') as f:
        finput = f.read()
    cards = CARDMATCHER.findall(finput)
    return [MyVCard(card) for card in cards]

print([{"fn":card.info['FN'], "tel":card.get_a_number()} for card in get_vcards(file)])
```

Again, I make no guarantees on this code since I'm not going to look up all the specifications for the `vcf` format, and would recommend using a module specifically designed for this instead.